# Most efficient algorithm to generate Random Prime Numbers in a range of bits

Tags: random

NTL/ZZ.h has a function which generates a Random Prime ZZ number for you (ZZ RandomPrime_ZZ(long, long)), i was wondering if any of you know which algorithm does NTL uses to achieve that. Otherwise, please commend a good algorithm you know that is efficient.
By "in a range of bits", i mean to generate primes of x bits depending on a parameter (e.g. 2048 bits).

Answer (score 0):

NTL (as of version 9.20, at least) generates random odd numbers with the appropriate bit length and tests them with the given number of Miller-Rabin tests (10, by default). If they're tested as being composite it starts over, otherwise it returns the (probable-prime) number.

`GenPrime` does the same thing, but instead of giving it a number of tests you give it a number indicating the maximum failure probability you're willing to accept (the default, 80, means it can fail up to once every 2^80 ≈ 10^24 attempts on average. It uses a deep result of Damgård, Landrock, & Pomerance (1993) to compute the number of tests needed.